# What is stopping me from installing npm packages please check the code and tell me. Unable to install any library

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

IMP: My PC is windows 10 32 bit

> (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

Is this the reason ?

```
E:\My Projects\app>npm i faker
npm WARN @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.3.3 requires a peer of ajv@>=8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @react-aria/ssr@3.1.2 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.1 requires a peer of typescript@>= 2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 
3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

+ faker@6.6.6
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1424 packages in 53.178s

173 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 4 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in there.

It's just warn-informing you that `fsevents` is a Mac-only (`darwin` is the codename for macOS) package and won't be installed on your Windows box.

Based on "audited 1424 packages" you already have 1424 packages installed, so there's seemingly nothing stopping you from installing packages.

Comment: Also one more issue is there, I'm trying to use useContext > context in index.js

import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import Context from './components/Context';



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Context> 
        <App />
</Context>
)

But it shows blank page. What wrong did i do ?

Comment: That's an absolutely different question, and you can't just "drive-by" ask it in a comment. You will need to look for errors in your browser console, in any case.

Comment: I tried to add another question but  my question limit got exceeded for today. Never mind! I'll figure out.